# Graphql Error: Network Request Failed only in Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, hasura

All my queries work well in iOS but give a network request failed error in Android. Some other SO and GitHub solutions suggest that I shouldn't be using `localhost` for my `uri` and should use my computer's IP address. But I am already not using localhost.

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'https://gateway_dev.companyName.en/v1/graphql',
  });

  const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    const token = await auth().currentUser?.getIdToken();
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
      },
    };
  });

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({}),
  });

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
...
```

The uri I am using is the Graphql Endpoint POST url from my Hasura console. I am testing by using an Android emulator from the Android Studio and not on a real device. What else could I try?

I also tried adding this `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to **AndroidManifest.xml** file but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: could you try a random fetch call in your code ? and check if that works

Comment: I mean fetch or axios call to a random api like dog api https://dog.ceo/dog-api/ if you get response to discard if a config issue or related to apollo

Comment: are you sure your android emulator has access to internet?

Comment: It used to work with a different api link so I guess the internet connection isn't a problem. Also, I tested in on a real android device and the issue still exists. @AlexShtromberg

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz haven't worked with fetch or axios before. Couldn't find a relevant axios example that I could run on maybe a button press. Could you give me a concrete example? Would be really helpful

Comment: axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });

Comment: Just checked. This also gives me a network error. What should I try then? @anthonywillismuñoz

Comment: your emulator doesn't have access to internet, that's why axios doesn't work as well

Comment: Changing my uri from https to http just worked somehow @AlexShtromberg