# TypeError - Network Request Failed (no hint where problem is)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I face big complications here, my app doesnt start up and I get this strange error I havent faced before. Im running my app via Expo, just as a sidenote.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
>
> - node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4
>   in __callFunction
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6
>   in __guard$argument_0
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10
>   in __guard
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4
>   in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>
> - [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

I tried already to reinstall expo - did not help me in any way.

3 Weeks ago when I started my break from coding everything worked fine. I dont know what is the problem, the error is not pointing at any special part of the code. I can provide you with any informations needed, because at this point I dont even know where I should start to look for any errors.

Comment: I am also not using localhost. It is a remote server that returns the data fine from the browser.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an emulator then the issue could be that the localhost on Android/ios is pointing to the emulated Android/ios device, and not to the machine on which your server is running.

The solution is to replace localhost with the IP address of your machine. Try changing `http://localhost:4000` by `http://10.0.2.2:4000/`

I picked this up from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362059/network-error-typeerror-network-request-failed) Maybe this helps

Comment: Im using expo on a simulator but also on a real device, on both its failing. I dont think this is an issue with my simulator :/

Comment: Did you give this a try if not maybe you may want to give it a try and see if it works. Now, if it does not work then the most obvious place to hunt the issue is to look into the URL of the fetch requests you are making. Use try & catch to console log the error.

Comment: Problem is, I have nowhere in my app code like this "http://localhost:4000" which I could change. The only thing I can do is probably check all my URLs of the fetch requests I do

Comment: Yes @KubaghettothefreshTestobun the issue must be in any of the URLs use try and catch.

Comment: I did it and I think I found the source of the problem in my project. I opened a new ticket here in stackoverflow and posted all relevant data and screenshots, maybe you could look into that, would be insanely kind. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193839/redux-action-function-doesnt-execute-properly-expo-possible-undandled-promise

Comment: The famous missing character. The enemy that keeps developers awake at night.. lol

Answer (score 0):

It is because your whatwg-fetch stop connection to this url because multiple calls at a time
so,
Just Change your Route name
i.e, for eg:
if your Url is like "http://10.0.2.2:4000/login" change it to something with new name like "http://10.0.2.2:4000/loginuser" and try