# redux action function doesnt execute properly - expo "possible undandled promise rejection"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-redux, expo

I have a really strange problem facing at this point and I dont know precisely how to describe it so I will try to first show you all the data that is relevant:

**this is the code of the function:**

```
export const fetchPigeons = () => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const PersonalId = getState().auth.userId;
        const response = await fetch(`https://pigeonbuddy-*****.firebaseio.com/users/${PersonalId}/pigeons.json`);
        const resData = await response.json();
        const jsonValue = await fetch('https://geolocation-db.com/json/85****90-4601-11eb-9067-21b51bc8dee3').then((response) => response.json()).then((json) => {return json.country_code});
        console.log("123", jsonValue); //Logging of the Location!

        console.log(resData);
        const loadedPigeons = []; //create new empty array
        for (var key in resData){ //load up new created array with pigeons from server
            console.log("VOGEL DETECTED");
            switch(resData[key].id){
                case 1:
                    var tempPigeon = ALLPIGEONS[0];
                    tempPigeon.key = key;
                    loadedPigeons.push(tempPigeon);
                    continue;
                case 2:
                    var tempPigeon = ALLPIGEONS[1];
                    tempPigeon.key = key;
                    loadedPigeons.push(tempPigeon);
                    continue;
                case 3: 
                    var tempPigeon = ALLPIGEONS[2];
                    tempPigeon.key = key;
                    loadedPigeons.push(tempPigeon);
                    continue;
                case 4: 
                    var tempPigeon = ALLPIGEONS[3];
                    tempPigeon.key = key;
                    loadedPigeons.push(tempPigeon);
                    continue;
                case 5:
                    var tempPigeon = ALLPIGEONS[4];
                    tempPigeon.key = key;
                    loadedPigeons.push(tempPigeon);
                    continue;
                case 6:
                    var tempPigeon = ALLPIGEONS[5];
                    tempPigeon.key = key;
                    loadedPigeons.push(tempPigeon);
                    continue;
                default:
                    console.log("Not working");
            }
        };
        console.log("hier sind meine vögel: ", loadedPigeons);
        dispatch({type: SET_PIGEONS, pigeons: loadedPigeons, location: jsonValue})
    }
};
```

What Im doing here is basicly searching if the user has pigeons and if thats the case, store them localy by id.

Im doing this by calling the action in my other documents like that:

```
import * as authActions from '../store/actions/auth';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
//some other code
useDispatch(pigeonActions.fetchPigeons());
```

The problem is that both console.log() orders are not working, JS is simply not even noticing me waiting for a response, the terminal doesnt show up anything, I mean this both logs:

```
console.log("123", jsonValue); //Logging of the Location!
console.log(resData);
```

I already checked if the fetch orders are maybe buggy but thats not the case, I definetly get values from firebase at least, it seems like after I fetch data from geolocation-db the whole function stops to execute without any error and just does nothing anymore.

The only message expo delivers me which I cant really work with is this here:

[image]

[image]

Im feeling really helpless at this point and dont know what to do anymore.
The only thing about the warning is that its referencing multiple times to 192.168.178.43:19001 even tho in my browser window expo tells me im running on 192.168.178.43:19000 and you can see it here:
[image]

I will try to provide you with any infos and code samples if necessary, at this point I dont know anymore what to do. Any info is appriciated!

Comment: First check packager-info.json file in .expo folder. What does  "devToolsPort", "expoServerPort", & "packagerPort": point to? Second please confirm what does package.json "scripts": { "start":  } pointing towards? is it "expo start"?

Comment: Oh my god I hate your `switch` statement!  The index is just `id - 1`, no need to `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `useDispatch` hook correctly.  You need to call `useDispatch()` with no arguments in order to access to the `dispatch` function.  Then you use that function to dispatch actions.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const load = () => {
  dispatch(pigeonActions.fetchPigeons());
}
```

If you want to dispatch the action automatically then you would do that with a `useEffect` hook.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(pigeonActions.fetchPigeons());
}, []);
```

---

The "possible unhandled promise rejection" is warning you that you will have runtime errors if the `fetch` requests in your `fetchPigeons` action fail.  You want to `catch` these errors.  It is typical to dispatch a failure action when errors are caught within an async action creator.

```
export const fetchPigeons = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      /**... your code ...**/
      dispatch({type: SET_PIGEONS, pigeons: loadedPigeons, location: jsonValue})
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({type: FETCH_PIGEONS_ERROR, error: error?.message})
    }
  }
};
```

I recommend using the [`createAsyncThunk` function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) from the official Redux Toolkit which automatically dispatches "pending", "fulfilled", and "rejected" actions.

---

Your handling of the response can be cleaned up majorly, but I'm not understanding where this `ALLPIGEONS` variable comes from?  This is your current logic in a lot less lines.

```
const loadedPigeons = Object.keys(resData).map((key) => {
  const id = resData[key].id;
  return {
    ...ALLPIGEONS[id - 1],
    key
  };
});
```

But I really doubt that your intention is to disregard everything from the response except the `key`.